# Python and Line Breaks

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

With Python I know that the "\n" breaks to the next line in a string, but what I am trying to do is replace every "," in a string with a '\n'. Is that possible? I am kind of new to Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
text = 'a, b, c'
text = text.replace(',', '\n')
print text
```

For lists:

```
text = ['a', 'b', 'c']
text = '\n'.join(text)
print text
```

Comment: I am trying to excepting it but the website keeps giving me an error about how I have to wait 5 minutes before I can except it.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> str = 'Hello, world'  
>>> str = str.replace(',','\n')  
>>> print str  
Hello  
 world

>>> str_list=str.split('\n')
>>> print str_list
['Hello', ' world']
```

For futher operations you may check: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: How would you do this with a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a literal `\n` into your string by escaping the backslash, e.g.

```
>>> print '\n'; # prints an empty line

>>> print '\\n'; # prints \n
\n
```

The same principle is used in regular expressions. Use this expresion to replace all `,` in a string with `\n`:

```
>>> re.sub(",", "\\n", "flurb, durb, hurr")
'flurb\n durb\n hurr'
```

Comment: I wasn't asking about how to escape the \n I was asking how to replace the character ',' with '\n' in a string.