# Python List Replace

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python and Line Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693732/python-and-line-breaks)

In Python I know that when your handling strings you can use "replace" to replace a certain character in a string. For example:

```
h = "2,3,45,6"
h = h.replace(',','\n')
print h

Returns:
2
3
45
6
```

Is there anyway to do this with a list? For example replace all the "," in a list with "\n"?

A list like:

```
h = ["hello","goodbye","how are you"]

"hello"
"goodbye"
"how are you"
```

And the Script should output something like this:

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean; give a short example of a list you would like to apply it to.

Comment: Certainly, but the details depend on whether you have a list of characters or a list of smaller strings (e.g. lines). Please give an example input and output.

Comment: That is not a list of strings, so it does not contain a `","` in the first place. What output would you want to get from this? If `"2\n5\n6\n8\n9"`, then `"\n".join(h)` should work. It's not actually "replacing", though.

Comment: I fixed the question and now it should be easier to anwser

Comment: Doh, forgot the `str()`. Anyway, what @Abhijit says.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your example and desire, you can use the [str.join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and this is probably what you want

```
>>> h
['2', '3', '45', '6']
>>> print '\n'.join(str(i) for i in h)
2
3
45
6
```

similarly for your second example

```
>>> h = ["hello","goodbye","how are you"]
>>> print '\n'.join(str(i) for i in h)
hello
goodbye
how are you
```

If you really wan't the quotation mark for strings you can use the following

```
>>> h = ["hello","goodbye","how are you"]
>>> print '\n'.join('"{0}"'.format(i) if isinstance(i,str) else str(i) for i in h)
"hello"
"goodbye"
"how are you"
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use list comprehension for that:

```
>>> search = 'foo'
>>> replace = 'bar'
>>> lst = ['my foo', 'foo', 'bip']
>>> print [x.replace(search, replace) for x in lst]
['my bar', 'bar', 'bip']
```

Answer (score 1):

In a list like your `h = [2,5,6,8,9]`, there really are no commas to replace in the list itself. The list contains the items `2`, `5` and so on, the commas are merely part of the external representation to make it easier to separate the items visually.

So, to generate some output form from the list but without the commas, you can use any number of techniques. For instance, to join them all up into a single string without commas, use:

```
"".join([str(x) for x in h])
```

This will evaluate to `25689`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for each in h: print each
```

In 3.x:

```
for each in h: print(each)
```

A list is simply a representation of data. You can only affect the way it looks in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the ',' in the string because the ',' is part of the string itself but you cannot replace the ',' in a list because it is not an item in the list rather it is what is used by python for delineating different items in such a list together with the opening and closing square brackets. It is just like asking if you could replace the '"' used in creating the string. On the other hand if the ',' is an item in the list and you want to replace it with a newline item then you could use list comprehensions like:

```
['\n' if x=="," else x for x in yourlist]
```

or if you want to print each item on a single line you could use:

```
for item in list:
    print item
```